# Removing duplicates from an array of numbers

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program in C++ where I input a series of numbers into `a[]` and then the numbers get outputted into `b[]` removing any duplicates. for example `a[] = {1,3,7,6,3,7}` would output `b[] = {1,3,7,6}`. Thanks!

```
int main() {
  int a[10];

  int i, n, j;

  cout << "n=";

  cin >> n;

  for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
    cout << "a[" << i << "]=";

    cin >> a[i];
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

  {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)

    {
      if (a[i] == a[j]) {
        cout << "b= " << a[i] << endl;
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    if (a[i] != a[j]) {
      cout << "b=" << a[i] << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, please, format the code so we can read it.

Comment: You can highlight the code in the editor, and then the `{}` icon to indent it all four spaces. That will make the code more legible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should change to this (the order of array will not be respected in neither of code snippets):

```
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    bool notDup = true;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
      if (a[i] == a[j]) {
          notDup = false;
          break;
      }
    }
    if(notDup)
        cout << "b= " << a[i] << endl;
  }
```

However easier solution to your problem is constructing a [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), it will omit the duplicates.

```
vector<int> a{1,3,7,6,3,7};
set<int> b(a.begin(), a.end());
for (auto& elem : b)
{
    std::cout<<elem<<'\n';
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/f0r2mJ)

Answer (score 3):

if you like to rid of duplicates (and retain the order) then C++ idiomatic way of doing it be to use std::set and std::vector (showing here only a relevant snippet for your example):

```
int a[] = {1,3,7,6,3,7};
std::set<int> c;
std::vector<int> b;

for(auto v: a)
 if(c.insert(v).second)
  b.push_back(v);

for(auto v: b)
 std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

output:

```
1
3
7
6
```

Comment: Retains the first seen order.  Nice.

Comment: You should use `unordered_map` so that insertion is O(1) instead of O(lg n).

Comment: @0x499602D2, it's debatable and depends on the typical size of the input data: if dealing with big input data, the `unordered_map`  will start growing buckets for colliding keys, which will inevitably degrade O(1) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `std::unordered_set` to keep track of which elements you've already kept.  Also, use `std::vector` instead of C-style arrays.

```
vector<int> a{1, 3, 7, 6, 3, 7}, 
            b;
unordered_set<int> s;
for(auto i : a)
{
    if (s.insert(i).second)
    {
        b.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to remove duplicates from vector.

From `Oblivion` solution, easy way would be insert them into a set and then get value from the set.

```
vector<int> a{1,3,7,6,3,7};
set<int> b(a.begin(), a.end());
for (auto& elem : b)
{
    std::cout<<elem<<'\n';
}
```

Another way would be use ***unique*** in place which is available in [STL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-stl-tutorial/). If you don't want to use more memory then this solution is perfect. It's time complexity is `O(nlogn)`.

```
vector<int> a{1,3,7,6,3,7};
sort(a.begin(), a.end()); 
a.erase(unique(a.begin(), a.end()), a.end());
```